# How do I use UIActivity Indicator with NSUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using NSUrlConnection for accessing data from server.
I want that during fetching of the data from the server the user interactivity is stopped as well as the code execution.

And I read more and more on Stack Overflow or Google, but I'm not get appropriate solution.

Please see the code which I'm using.

The first time when the user clicks to access the data from the server I start the activity indicator.

```
[activity startAnimating];


NSString *post = 
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Pass=%@",Email,pass];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.in/LoginStatus.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];  


NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{

    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{


}
```

and in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` function I stop the activity indicator.

The problem is that when I check the returned data then it displays the previous result. When clicked again it display the proper result.

Please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: you should post the complete code, together with the didRecieveData and connectionDidFinish..

Answer (score 0):

Try run the UIActivityIndicator and the NSURLConnection in different threads. I had the problem that the Indicator didn't show up when the Connection was alive. Putting both in seperate Threads solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
[activity startAnimating];
within your method

now try to make the NSURL Connection in some thread.And call the thread from your method
and once the connection get Finish use
[activity stopAnimating];

Will definitely work